# Browser crashing when trying to save anything

Tags: windows, browser, save-as

I am using Windows 8.1. Every time I try to save a thing in Chrome or Firefox, just after a Operating System boot, the browser crashes and freezes. This also happens with the Windows Snipping Tool. I have to kill them in the task manager, and start the app again. Only after this I am able to save whatever I want. It seems like a sort of file system problem, I guess. I have searched the Microsoft troubleshooting but finding nothing. Does anyone can help me?

**UPDATE 1**
I have followed the instructions from @robcalewar, and it has been finished with some errors that can be seen in this log file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzarpDINYu9fOWFERDdGanJXTVE

Can anyone have an ideia about what I can do to solve the problem?

Comment: You have to tell us what a "SO boot" is exactly.

Comment: Thanx, @Ramhound. I have corrected the mispelling.

Comment: I'm going to have to suspect a filesystem issue. Try running chkdsk and report back with your results.

Comment: @bwDraco I made an update with a link to the check disk log file.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like it could be a potentially failing drive. Check your hard drive's smart results. I usually recommend using [crystalDiskInfo](http://crystalmark.info/download/index-e.html). If that doesn't work you can also open up a command prompt as an Admin and run the command "sfc /scannow" this will verify (and attempt) to repair any system files that may be damaged.

Just make sure that you check the harddrive health first. If you repair damaged files on a failing hard drive you're just fixing something that will quickly break again.

---

**UPDATE 1**

what were the SMART results? The error from the sfc scans is minor and is not the cause of your problem.

I'd like to attempt to repair that issue found in the sfc scan you need to run "Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth" in the command prompt as admin.

Comment: Thanx @robcalewar. I will try this.

Comment: I have added a log file @robcalewar.

Comment: I have fixed the link to log file. Please, check it out again.